# Distance for each intersected points of a line in increased order in 2D coordinate

Tags: python, geometry, scipy, distance, intersection

I am calculating the distance between A(x0,y0) and B(x1,y1) points in a 2D (x,y).

I have the following code which represents intersected points of each cell in the given two boundary points, A(x0,y0) and B(x1,y1).

```
def intersected_points(x0, x1, y0, y1):
    # slope 
    m = (y1 - y0 )/( x1 - x0)
    # Boundary of the selected points
    x_ceil = ceil( min (x0, x1 ))
    x_floor = floor( max(x0, x1))
    y_ceil = ceil( min(y0, y1))
    y_floor = floor( max(y0, y1))

    # calculate all intersected x coordinate
    ax = []
    for x in arange(x_ceil, x_floor + 1, 1):
          ax.append([ x, m * ( x - x0 ) + y0 ])
    # calculate all intersected y coordinate
    for y in arange(y_ceil, y_floor + 1, 1):
          ax.append([ ( y - y0 ) * ( 1./m ) + x0, y ])
    return ax
```

**Sample values:**

```
intersected_points(1.5, 4.4, 0.5, 4.1);
```

**Output:**

```
[
    [2.0, 1.1206896551724137],
    [3.0, 2.3620689655172411],
    [4.0, 3.6034482758620685],
    [1.9027777777777779, 1.0],
    [2.7083333333333335, 2.0],
    [3.5138888888888893, 3.0],
    [4.3194444444444446, 4.0]
]
```

The output I got is mixed and unsorted values, so, for each cell coordinates, where line crosses.
BUT, The result I want to get should be something (**including boundary points**): **(x0,y0)**, all intersected points, **(x1,y1)**
where x0, y0 - intial, x1,y1 - final point. Other values are intersected line coordinates!

Comment: It looks like you could just append `[x0, y0]` and `[x1, y1]` to `ax` and then sort `ax` before returning it.

Comment: I don't see where you are computing *distance*.

Comment: Distance here is the difference between the points that you found like: (x1-x0), (x2-x1), (x3-x2), (x4-x3),... this is what I would like to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a modified version of your code.  It uses numpy a bit more, and it includes the end points in the sorted array of points.

```
import numpy as np

def intersected_points(x0, x1, y0, y1):
    # slope
    m = (y1 - y0) / (x1 - x0)
    # Boundary of the selected points
    x_ceil = np.ceil(min(x0, x1))
    x_floor = np.floor(max(x0, x1))
    y_ceil = np.ceil(min(y0, y1))
    y_floor = np.floor(max(y0, y1))

    # calculate all intersected x coordinate
    x = np.arange(x_ceil, x_floor + 1)
    y = m * (x - x0) + y0
    ax = zip(x, y)
    # calculate all intersected y coordinate
    y = np.arange(y_ceil, y_floor + 1)
    x = (y - y0) / m + x0
    ax.extend(zip(x, y))
    ax.append((x0, y0))
    ax.append((x1, y1))
    ax.sort()
    return np.array(ax)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    x0, y0 = 1.5, 0.5
    x1, y1 = 4.4, 4.1

    points = intersected_points(x0, x1, y0, y1)
    print points

    rect = plt.Rectangle((x0, y0), x1 - x0, y1 - y0,
                         facecolor="#60ff60", alpha=0.2)
    plt.gca().add_patch(rect)
    plt.plot([x0, x1], [y0, y1], 'b-')
    plt.plot(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], 'bo')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.xticks(np.arange(np.floor(x0), np.ceil(x1)))
    plt.yticks(np.arange(np.floor(y0), np.ceil(y1)))
    plt.show()
```

It prints:

```
[[ 1.5         0.5       ]
 [ 1.90277778  1.        ]
 [ 2.          1.12068966]
 [ 2.70833333  2.        ]
 [ 3.          2.36206897]
 [ 3.51388889  3.        ]
 [ 4.          3.60344828]
 [ 4.31944444  4.        ]
 [ 4.4         4.1       ]]
```

and generates the plot:

[image: plot of grid intersection points]

Comment: THanks Warren for the modified code! After having calculated croseed Line length I will calculate distance between two points. That will be done by Pythagoras theorem (no problem). Also, I have another Matrix that represents x,y axis length. Let'say **Matrix(MxN) = (150x120) with some random values**. Each step in Matrix is 250 meter, say, 0.25km.                                                 The problem is to **respectively** calculate Matrix(MxN)*intersected_line_length. Is it possible without taking into account **balance between Matrix coordinate and line coordinate** ? Thanks in advance

Comment: That sounds like a new question.  If you start a new question, it would help if you gave a complete example of what you are trying to accomplish--maybe show one complete example that you have worked out "by hand", and ask how to accomplish it with code.

Comment: Hi, Warren I have encountered the problem while I was testing the code with some other values. For example, x0, y0 = 0.6, 0.21; x1, y1 = 0.78,0.65. Also, dx = 0.25 instead of 1, grid size_height and _width = 0.25, I got wrong values.. How can it be resolved?